# Converting canvas to pdf

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, canvas

I've been looking into this for a while, but the closest thing I've come up with is .toDataUrl(), which seems to only be used for bitmap image formats. What I really need is to be able to save the canvas contents to a pdf, and be able to specify page breaks where appropriate. Is there a function in javascript to do so, or will I have to do this with an apache command line tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try pdf.js....idk if it'll work with canvas off the bat, but worth a looksie
http://badassjs.com/post/708922912/pdf-js-create-pdfs-in-javascript

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/andreasgal/pdf.js)

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to generate PDF documents using Javascript, but I'm yet to come across a framework that is mature enough to use.

What you could do is use some PHP PDF library, such as [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/), and post your image data to a PHP script that generates the PDF document. Better yet you could use the AJAX method to generate the PDF without a page refresh.

When attaching images just specify the data URL as the image URL (although I haven't tested, it should work).