# Google Chrome App print slient

Tags: google-chrome, printing, google-chrome-app, kiosk-mode

It's possible in a Google Chrome App print silent like when Chrome is running in kiosk mode?

```
--kiosk --kiosk-priting
```

Comment: What do you mean by print? Print to printer? Print to `console`?

Comment: Yes, print to printer. Something like this [link](http://support.vendhq.com/entries/21006382-Enable-kiosk-silent-printing-for-Google-Chrome-on-Windows-Video-) but as Google Chrome App. Thanks!

Comment: You want to print from a background/event page, right?

Comment: Exactly,from a background/event page to the default printer.

Comment: Is there a possibility of adding an [application/device in the environment which can listen to WebSocket events](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28783269/3196753)?

Answer (score 0):

When you print something in kiosk mode things gets printed automatically to the default printer, silently. Simply call `print()` in the context of the page you want to print. If you want to print from the background/event page you will need to do something like the following:

```
// ...
function closePrint () {
  document.body.removeChild(this.__container__);
}

function setPrint () {
  this.contentWindow.__container__ = this;
  this.contentWindow.onbeforeunload = closePrint;
  this.contentWindow.onafterprint = closePrint;
  this.contentWindow.print();
}

function printPage (sURL) {
  var oHiddFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
  oHiddFrame.onload = setPrint;
  oHiddFrame.style.visibility = "hidden";
  oHiddFrame.style.position = "fixed";
  oHiddFrame.style.right = "0";
  oHiddFrame.style.bottom = "0";
  oHiddFrame.src = sURL;
  document.body.appendChild(oHiddFrame);
}
//...
```

Simply call `printPage`, passing a URL, to print something.

<sub><sup>Code from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Printing#Examples)</sup></sub>

Comment: Ok, that it's util for background event but my problem is the print preview dialogue is open and need the user action to confirm de printing. When you're using chrome in --kiosk --kiosk-priting print starts automatically. I want to do this but in a Chrome Google App.

Comment: Start chrome with the `--kiosk` and `--kiosk-priting` and then open the app and print. That works, right?

Comment: Yes it works, but it's something that I don't want because is one more thing that user need to do. I was searching something like Websockets and Network Communication as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217687/is-it-possible-to-access-printer-installed-in-network-in-google-chrome-packaged?rq=1

Thanks!

Comment: You simply configure your remote printer and set it as the default. No  web sockets required.

Comment: How to do that to avoid print preview confirmation?

Comment: Start chrome with the `--kiosk` and `--kiosk-priting` flags!

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary (maybe not temporary :) ) solution for this subject:

SOLUTION FOR CHROME APP

1. Install your App to chrome
2. Create shortcut from this app to desktop.
3. Right click > Properties > Edit Target Textbox like the below  (you will add "--kiosk-printing" parameter )

   Before Edit: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 2" --app-id=eoaefbbbpgcbhgeilphgobiicboopknp

   After Edit:  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" **--kiosk-printing** --profile-directory="Profile 2" --app-id=eoaefbbbpgcbhgeilphgobiicboopknp
4. Absolutely restart chrome for effect (close every tabs and windows on chrome)
5. Try to print
6. If you want to remove default header and footer (page address and date) : Open normal chrome print something > on printer preview  > More Settings > uncheck "Header and Footer". Chrome ll remember this settings always.

(In fact chrome must provide this property on manifest.json too, but i couldnt find yet)

Answer (score 0):

I have setting:

1. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk-printing --profile-directory="Profile 1"
2. Website testing with jquery library
   https://printjs.crabbly.com/
   Chrome Popup printer auto close and not print out..