# Run silent print via Chrome App in Kiosk mode

Tags: printing, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os, chromium-os

Does anyone know a way to silent print via a Chrome App?

I'm developing a chrome app for a KIOSK system which runs Chromium OS. I need to print a receipt via a Chrome App, which I already did. The problem is that print dialog box appears once print process is started.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Check my answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22357398/google-chrome-app-print-slient/32435013#32435013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're specifically targeting Kiosk mode apps, you just need to set a flag.

Specifically, `--kiosk-printing`

I'm not 100% sure how to do that on a Chrome OS device in Kiosk mode. Maybe you need to set it at `chrome://flags` before switching to Kiosk mode.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a way to make this work (because this was specifically added for your scenario!), I just don't know how to properly activate the option on Chrome OS Kiosk mode.

Comment: Thanks. I installed ubuntu server on my KIOSK machine. I tried --kiosk -printing. but it did not work. I'll post here If I find anything. thanks.

Comment: @amilaishere Care to share what went wrong and what you eventually fixed?

Comment: It's being a while . But As I remembered firstly I tried it with windows OS. Since our kiosk system runs on a Ubuntu 14.04 I was working with linux. Eventually It has worked.

Comment: @xan This is only for chrome apps? It does not appear to work on chrome browser on os x 10.13.6

Answer (score 3):

This is IMPORTANT INFORMATION about  kiosk mode Chrome app

Kiosk parameters  can not be useful when you install app in developer mode (1)  ( Parameters = "kiosk_enabled":true and "kiosk_only":true   located in manifest.json )

But  the parameters work after install the app from Chrome Store. Therefore be careful about this trick.

Now my kiosk app can run full screen and silent print (without preview).

[image]

1) http://lifehacker.com/install-chrome-extensions-from-outside-the-store-with-d-1596918011?disableinsets=off&utm_expid=66866090-49.VYy4WCNHSyuP6EmjnM93MQ.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.sa%2F

Answer (score 1):

I found a temporary (maybe not temporary :) ) solution for this subject:

SOLUTION FOR CHROME APP

Install your App to chrome

Create shortcut from this app to desktop.

Right click > Properties > Edit Target Textbox like the below (you will add "--kiosk-printing" parameter )

Before Edit: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 2" --app-id=eoaefbbbpgcbhgeilphgobiicboopknp

After Edit: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --kiosk-printing --profile-directory="Profile 2" --app-id=eoaefbbbpgcbhgeilphgobiicboopknp

Absolutely restart chrome for effect (close every tabs and windows on chrome)
Try to print

If you want to remove default header and footer (page address and date) : Open normal chrome print something > on printer preview > More Settings > uncheck "Header and Footer". Chrome ll remember this settings always.

(In fact chrome must provide this property on manifest.json too, but i couldnt find yet)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry man, it's not possible.

But you could evaluate some workaround: install a web server, make an httpRequest, and then print using a server side language.

In my case, I used php to receive the http request from the chrome app, and then, from php, I launched a java app for the print. I used java because with php (php_printer.dll) is not possible to print images (it's possible to print bmp, but the process to convert a png to an bmp is too long).

I know, it's a little tricky, but it works.

Comment: Hmm, seems like it might be work for me as well. I'll let you know if I accomplished the task. thakns